# How can I make yellow on white more visible in a plot?

Tags: plotting, style

I'd like to use this color combination in a plot but for obvious reasons the yellow is hard to see. Obvious solutions would be to use other colors or change the background, but this is not what I'm looking for.

How can I make it more visible, e.g. applying a border or some subtle background shadow?

```
Plot[{1 + 1/8 Cos[2 x], 3/2 + 1/8 Cos[2 x]}, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, RGBColor[255, 223, 0]}]
```

Comment: This might be useful: `ResourceFunction["FontColorFromBackgroundColor"]`. Yellow is on White with little contrast compared to Blue oder Black. Just a thin line and glow is not an appropriate solution. Take a darker Yellow with `Darker`!

Comment: @SteffenJaeschke I tried `Darker[Yellow]` but it doesn't really look yellow anymore.

Comment: I notice that you did not Accept an answer to this question. Is there 
something that remains to be addressed?

Comment: @eldo I usually give it some time to not discourage other people from answering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since V 13.3 we have `Haloing`

```
Plot[{1 + 1/8 Cos[2 x], 3/2 + 1/8 Cos[2 x]}, {x, 0, \[Pi]},
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Haloing[RGBColor[255, 223, 0]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Using `DropShadowing`:** (new in 13.1)

```
Plot[{1 + 1/8 Cos[2 x], 3/2 + 1/8 Cos[2 x]}
, {x, 0, π}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue,{ DropShadowing[],Yellow}}
 ]
```

[image]

---

For older versions:

Plot the second curve twice.

```
Plot[{1 + 1/8 Cos[2 x]
  , 3/2 + 1/8 Cos[2 x]
  , 3/2 + 1/8 Cos[2 x]
  }
 , {x, 0, π}, PlotStyle -> {Blue
   , Lighter@RGBColor[255, 223, 0]
   , {Thickness[0.001], Dotted, Black}
   }]
```

[image]